# Filter pictures in the media library

Tags: media-library

I have some issues with duplicated pictures in my media library and I would like to know if there is any option to show or automatically filter only certain images in the library.

For instance, let's say that I have 20 pictures in the library: A.jpg (original), B.jpg (original), C.jpg (original), A1.jpg (duplicate), A2.jpg (duplicate), B1.jpg (duplicate), C1.jpg (duplicate), etc.

I would like to see or to let see to other users only the first three pictures in the media library. Any idea how to do it with a plugin or modifying some files?

Thank you